# Set boolean field on access db with pyodbc

Tags: ms-access, pyodbc

I use pyodbc with Access DB.

I can add a bool (YES/NO) column in access with this command:

```
crsr.execute("alter table "+tableName+" add column {} {}".format(name, type))
```

Now I try to modify my field with these commands but they didn't work :

```
crsr.execute( "update " + tableName +" set tutu='1' "  )
crsr.execute( "update " + tableName +" set tutu=1 "  )
crsr.execute( "update " + tableName +" set tutu=True "  )
crsr.execute( "update " + tableName +" set tutu='True' "  )
crsr.execute( "update " + tableName +" set tutu=true "  )
```

Now I'm using integer field with 0 and 1 like values

Can you help me for using bool field ?

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access encodes booleans in the following curious way:

`True` is `-1`, `False` = `0`

Note that I believe the main reason `tutu=True` doesn't work, is the missing spaces.

You can try the following:

```python
crsr.execute( "update " + tableName +" set tutu = True "  )
```

Or

```python
crsr.execute( "update " + tableName +" set tutu = -1 "  )
```

Comment: No, it's not a lack of spaces. `set tutu=True`, `set tutu=False`, `set tutu=Yes`, and `set tutu=No` all work fine for a properly-defined Yes/No field in an Access table, at least with the Access 2010 version of the ODBC driver.